# Dynamic addition of panel

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic

I realize that a similar question has been asked on here multiple times, but I cannot figure out why my code is not working.

I'm trying to add a panel only when the int variable `selected` is equal to `0`. When I run my code I do not see my panel as I might expect.

My code is below:

```
if (selected == 0)
{      
    Panel p = new Panel();
    p.Height = 637;
    p.Width = 449;
    p.Location = new Point (269, 449);
    p.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    p.Visible = true;
    p.BackColor = Color.White;
    p.AllowDrop = true;
    p.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    p.Show();

    MessageBox.Show("Now we should see the Panel");                
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You created the panel in memory but haven't add it to your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a `Panel` but you don't add it to any controls collection.

You can do this using this code:

```
if (selected == 0)
{      
    Panel p = new Panel();
    p.Height = 637;
    p.Width = 449;
    p.Location = new Point (269, 449);
    p.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    p.Visible = true;
    p.BackColor = Color.White;
    p.AllowDrop = true;
    p.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    ///p.Show();
    this.Controls.Add(p);

    MessageBox.Show("Now we should see the Panel");                
}
```

If you want to add some controls to your `Panel` remember to:

- set `.Location` relatively to `Panel`
- use `p.Controls.Add(yourNewControl)`

Comment: Thank you all SO much!!  This was my first time using the "this" object and now so many things make sense again!!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're creating the panel, but you're not adding it on to your parent control (which I'm assuming is a Form).

You'll need to add something like the following:

```
this.Controls.Add(p);
```

So your total code will be something like this:

```
if (selected == 1)
{
  var p = new Panel();
  // Set some properties
  this.Controls.Add(p);
}
```

Comment: This actually makes things much simpler for me to understand!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

you need to add your panel to a parent control:

```
this.Controls.Add(panel);
```

I think you should read this [How to programmatically add controls to Windows forms at run time by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319266)